# CGContextRef not drawing

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawing

I'm trying to draw a circle for my Mac Application. The Code is:

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    NSPoint thePoint = [[self.window contentView] convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    NSLog(@"mouse moved: %f % %f",thePoint.x, thePoint.y);

    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(thePoint.x, thePoint.y, 20, 20);
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(circleRect.origin.x, circleRect.origin.y, 25, 25));
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
    [self needsDisplay];
}
```

`- (void)mouseMoved:` is called perfectly and I can see the correct x and y coordinates in NSLog. But I do not get any circles... surprisingly: If I'm **minimizing my application and reopening it** (so it "updates" NSView) **the circles are perfectly drawn**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mouseMoved` is **NOT** right place to draw anything, unless you're drawing onto the offscreen buffer. If you are going to draw on screen, save *thePoint* and any other necessary data, call `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` and draw in the `drawRect:(NSRect)rect` method.

Also, I can't see a reason to use `CGContextRef` while there is much more "friendly" `NSGraphicsContext`. Although, it's matter of taste.

An example of the drawing code:

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    // thePoint must be declared as the class member
    thePoint = [[self.window contentView] convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSRect ovalRect = NSMakeRect(thePoint.x - 100, thePoint.y - 100, 200, 200);
    NSBezierPath* oval = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:ovalRect];
    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [oval fill];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [oval stroke];
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm now using NSGraphicsContext, which really is friendly. By calling [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] the circle does not appear at all... Not even by minimizing and reopening. Without [self setNeedsDisplay:YES] I'm getting the circles after minimizing and reopening :(

Comment: I've updated answer. Use the code example, should work like a charm. Each time you face some issues in drawing method, I'd recommend to "start from the scratch": draw something, just something. Than check your updates methods, variable updating code (do you actually assign variable? do you assign local variables or member?), views refreshing. Step by step you will easily find the source of the problem.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do =D Thanks a lot!